# How do I get TableLayout occupy all available space vertically?

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout

I created a board dynamically and put in a LinearLayout ( Vertical ) together with a Chronometer and a Button . I gave the following weights for each of them :

Board : 5
Chronometer : 10
Button : 10

The chronometer button and take their correct places , however the board does not take up all your space on your height . Somebody help me, please?

Java class:

```js
tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabuleiro);

        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(azul);
        gd.setStroke(1, preto);

        final GradientDrawable gd2 = new GradientDrawable();
        gd2.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);
        gd2.setColor(Color.RED);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams =  new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

                textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
                textView.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                textView.setTag(String.valueOf(i + "." + j));

                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        v.setBackgroundDrawable(gd2);
                    }
                });

                tableRow.addView(textView, rowParams);
            }

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, tableParams);
        }
```

XML:

```js
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lnl"
    android:background="#a9c3ff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:id="@+id/tabuleiro"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="5">

        </TableLayout>

        <Chronometer
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/chrono"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/btn_voltar"
            android:id="@+id/btn_voltar"
            android:hyphenationFrequency="normal"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[IMAGE OF APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNEcY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lnl"
    android:background="#a9c3ff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:id="@+id/tabuleiro"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="5">

        </TableLayout>

        <Chronometer
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/chrono"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_voltar"
            android:id="@+id/btn_voltar"
            android:hyphenationFrequency="normal"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```